# Why does my Pop Up function not work as expected?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I will try to be as succinct and clear as possible! Half my problem is phrasing my question correctly ;)

I have set up a sticky pop up page on my site to collect emails for our newsletter, and I have set it up so that localStorage remembers the closed state of the pop up (so that visitors to our website don't get annoyed by it popping up on every page load).

That's working fine, but today I thought it would be good to add a button that when clicked could open the pop up (since it will stay closed until they clear their cache otherwise and they may want to access the pop up without knowing to do that).

I am using Weebly and the only option I have to get the button in the menu navigation is to add an external link page and then use javascript to strip the **http://** that gets inserted by Weebly and inject the code to call my pop up. This works, but what happens is that the pop up opens after closing it when I move to another page. Weirdly this only happens once and then the closed state is remembered.

This appears to be repeatable, so there must be a flaw in my logic/code but I can't work out what it is and would very much appreciate any tips or advice!

To see the button in question in action:

https://www.reclaimdesign.org

It's **+** on the far right of the top navigation menu.

The code called from the footer is:

```
<!--Use localStorage To Hide Signup Box If Closed-->
<script src="https://www.reclaimdesign.org/uploads/2/4/9/8/24985082/custom_themes/606760176814155089/files/hide-signup-min.js" async="async"></script>

$(window).on("load", function() {
        $("a[href='/page.html']").attr("href", "javascript:(function(){$('.signup').css('display', 'block');})()");
    });
```

And here is the code in the hide-signup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.signup').css('display', 'block');

$PopUp = $('.signup');

var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));

if (hide) {
    $PopUp.hide();
} else {
    // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
    localStorage.setItem('hide', false);
}

$('.closebtn').click(function() {
    $('.signup' ).hide();
    // toggle the boolean by negating its value
    var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));
    localStorage.setItem('hide', !hide);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening:

1- Initial load (new user): The hide is false as indicated in your code

2- User clicks close button: Hide becomes true

3- User click + button: Nothing happens (Should change hide to true in localstorage)

4- User clicks close button again: Hide becomes false (This causes the popup to show up on another page load)

On third step you need to make

```
localStorage.setItem('hide', false);
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for looking at this for me. Where should I be making that call? It is being set in the hide-signup.js at the moment?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMartin, you will be making that call when you detect a click on the + button in the main navigation. That is when you need to set 'hide' to false.

Comment: Thank you for your help Muhammad

Comment: You are welcome @MichaelMartin. You can mark the answer correct if that solved your problem.